# Why is this button not working?

Tags: javascript

I've recreated a problem in one of my projects. I have no idea why this doesn't work. It seems to fail when I add the textbox. For some reason, using a textbox is creating this error.

```
<input type="text" id="apple">
<input type="button" value="Go" id="banana">


<script>
var element = document.getElementById('apple');
var element2 = document.getElementById('banana');

element2.addEventListener("click", function(){

var test = element.value;

if (typeof test != "number"){
alert();
}

});
</script>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3mp0869s/8/

Comment: The value of an input is always a string, you want to **parse** it. Other than that, what "doesn't work" ?

Comment: Ahh, thanks. I will parse it.

Comment: working fine, but it will always display the alert because the type of 'test'

Comment: element.value;  returns string value. and your if condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
if (isNaN(test)){
alert("Not a number");
}
```

Here is your updated jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/3mp0869s/9/

Answer (score 2):

`element.value;` will return always string, so the condition will be never acheived, you should parse the value returned. or if you want just to check if the value of input is a number you can use `isNaN()` function :

```
if(isNaN(element.value)){
     alert('is not a number');
}else{
     alert('is a number');
}
```

**NOTE :** you can also use input with type `number` so you don't have to check.

Hope this helps.